# InRole Redirect Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-roles

I have my ID role as `technician`, so why doesn't `User.IsInRole` recognize it?

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("technician"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("tickets.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("servicerecords.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry sir i cant post image i dont have 10 reputation but i have set ID role as technician

Comment: Are you using asp.net membership? If so, check `aspnet_UsersInRoles` table and see if there's a record with `UserId` equals your user id from `aspnet_Users` table and `RoleId` equals the technician role id from `aspnet_Roles` table

Comment: i have set the technician name an EmployeeID from the database, the EmployeeID is set to use as userID and set it as Role technician

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider ?

Comment: You have properly setup the membership tables and specified the role provider in the web.config correct? Also, the user has logged in correct? Also ensure that the Application Name for the providers hasn't been changed after you set the role ids for a user since that will reset things. Also make sure the application names for membership and role providers match.

Comment: My problem is solved. I want to show it to you guys but I cant post answers LOL :D